# If/else not working with click event in jQuery

Tags: jquery, if-statement, click

I'm a beginner in jQuery and trying to have a bit of fun. I'm trying to make a button that will change the background of the page when clicked, as well as change the text of the button. I only need two scenarios:
 - if the button says "1", change the button to "2" and the background to black;
 - if the button says "2", change the button to "1" and the background to white;

My code works for the first click but you can't click more than once.

What did I do wrong? Thanks for your time.

http://jsfiddle.net/6fRbM/7/

This is my HTML

```
<body>
<button id="lumiere">1</button>
</body>
```

This is my script

```
$(function() {
    $('#lumiere').bind('click', function(event) {
        if ($('#lumiere:contains("1")')) {
            $('body').css('background-color', "black")
            $('#lumiere').html('2')
        }
        else if ($('#lumiere:contains("2")')) {
            $('body').css('background-color', "white")
            $('#lumiere').html('1')
        }
    }
    );
}
);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your if statement will always return true, because even if your query returns no elements, it will still give you a jQuery object. Try checking the 'length' property instead:

```
$(function() {
    $('#lumiere').bind('click', function(event) {
        if ($('#lumiere:contains("1")').length) {
            $('body').css('background-color', "black");
            $('#lumiere').html('2');
        }
        else if ($('#lumiere:contains("2")').length) {
            $('body').css('background-color', "white");
            $('#lumiere').html('1');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: While I commend you for actually explaining the problem (unlike most jQuery-posting users), I have to say I am amused that while jQuery prides itself on achieving more with less code, I have managed to perform the same task as you without jQuery in LESS code.

Comment: @Kolink I was merely answering the question asked. This is not the place to start a Vanilla vs jQuery debate.

Comment: Yes it is RAEG... nah, I'm kidding. You get a +1, which I don't usually give to jQuery answers ;)

Comment: Good answer and for first, but you missed the chance to teach something to the OP.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help guys. This fixed the code. Just to check if I understood correctly: checking the if/else like I did always returned something at the first if, thus ending the loop, whereas checking the length returns nothing when false ?

Comment: @Baralai When the query returns no elements, it will have a length of 0. 0 evaluates to false in an if statement. Any non-zero number will evaluate as true.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again! I'll be sure to come back and upvote as soon as I've unlocked that option.

Answer (score 1):

Refactoring a bit your code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#lumiere').click(function(event) {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.text() === '1') {
            $('body').css('background-color', "black");
            $this.text('2');
        }
        else if ($this.text() === '2') {
            $('body').css('background-color', "white");
            $this.text('1');
        }
    });
});
```

The optimizations are:

- `bind()` is old, use `on()` instead
- Use the `click()` shortcut
- No need to repeat selection inside your callback, just use `this`
- The Id selector is the fastest one, don't miss this opportunity using the :contains filter
- You don't need the filter at all because it isn't doing what you think. It test if the parameter you pass is **contained** in the text, not **equal**. So, if you need the latter, use `text()` instead.

Comment: If you're going to optimise using `$this`, surely you could also optimise the repeated call to `.text()`? :p

Comment: Actually one time is used as getter and the second as setter. So how you'll optimize it?

Comment: Are you serios, it is just 5 lines of code, whats wrong with you people.

Comment: Sometimes also 1 line of code is worth for a discussion on best practices.

Comment: I modified my code to take your input into account - used "click" with the .length suggested in the first answer. Unfortunately I can't upvote yet but I'll be sure to come back and do so as soon as I can!

Comment: @Baralai don't worry. Keep attention also to point 4 and 5. The 4th can speed-up your code while point 5 can better achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

Glad to see you're using jQuery. It's a very powerful tool and a lot of fun to use. Try the following:

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <button id="lumiere">1</button>
</body>
```

Keep your html as is.

**CSS:**

Add this class in the `<head></head>` section inside of a `<style type="text/css"></style>` block or in an external CSS file linked like so `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="external-sheet-name.css" />`.

```
.bodyRed {
    background-color: red;
}
```

This class will be used below in the JavaScript logic.

**JavaScript:**

Modify your JavaScript like the following:

```
var $body = $('body'),
    $button = $('#lumiere');

$button.on('click', function(event) {
    if($body.hasClass('bodyRed')) {
        $body.removeClass('bodyRed');
        $button.text('2');
    } else {
        $body.addClass('bodyRed');
        $button.text('1');
    }
});
```

Explanation:

The first two statements store references to your two jQuery objects. This is useful because it provides a way for jQuery to reference the objects without re-traversing the DOM each time. This is more efficient in the long run.

The second modification to your code is to change `bind` to `on`. `.on()` is the newer, more efficient, and preferred method for attaching event handlers. The link above will take you to the documentation for `.on()`.

The third modification is to remove the need for `inline` CSS by using the class created above. This also simplifies the logic. If the `<body>` tag has the class, remove it and change the button text. Otherwise, add it and then modify the button text.

That's all there is too it. To see it running in action, check out this live [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/BaASj/).

Good luck and happy coding! :)

Answer (score 1):

There's no need so much complications...

```
$(function() {
    $('#lumiere').bind('click', function(event) {
            var n = $('#lumiere').text();
            switch (n) {
            case '1':
                $('body').css('background-color', "black");
            $('#lumiere').text(2);
                break;
            case '2':
                $('body').css('background-color', "white");
            $('#lumiere').text(1);
                break;
            }            
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry for bad indentation!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
$('#lumiere').bind('click', function(event) {
     var v = parseInt($('#lumiere').text());

    if (v === 1) {
        $('body').css('background-color', "black")
        $('#lumiere').html('2')
    }
    else if (v === 2) {
        $('body').css('background-color', "white")
        $('#lumiere').html('1')
    }
}
);
```

}
);

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you use [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) for this task, it is much easier to use and much more efficient:

```
window.onload = function() { // if you place the script after the element,
                             // you can remove this line and the corresponding }
    document.getElementById('lumiere').onclick = function() {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = this.firstChild.nodeValue == 1 ? "black" : "white";
        this.firstChild.nodeValue = 3-this.firstChild.nodeValue;
    };
};
```

Comment: This has the added benefit of respecting DRY ^_^

Comment: Thanks a lot for your involvement Kolink. As soon as I'm done learning jQuery correctly, I'll be sure to take a look at Vanilla JS ;)

Comment: You should really learn Vanilla before you even consider jQuery, especially since jQuery uses Vanilla.

Comment: OK I'm really stupid, I thought "Vanilla JS" was another framework based on JS... but it IS JS! You're of course right, I do have some notions in JS but should really work more on it.

Comment: Hehe, I love the joke, it's funny to see people's reactions when they realise that ;) Seriously, though, my opinion is: "If you don't know Vanilla, then you shouldn't use jQuery. If you *do* know Vanilla, then you don't *need* jQuery."